# i am having trouble with the gotoAndPlay function in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

am doing a project and i have been using gotoAndPlay to go to a certian frame when i click a button. when i click the button it takes me to the frame but if i click it again it goes to the next frame it does it for all of my buttons(4)

```
activities.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoActivities);
function gotoActivities (event):void{
gotoAndPlay(255);
}
```

Do i need to disable the event listener when i enter the page and enable it again when i leave or is there another way in which i can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from within the handler itself.

```
activities.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoActivities);

function gotoActivities (event:MouseEvent):void{

  activities.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoActivities);

  gotoAndPlay(255);

}
```

or check for the [currentFrame](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame)

```
activities.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoActivities);

function gotoActivities (event:MouseEvent):void{

  if(this.currentFrame!=255) gotoAndPlay(255);

}
```